# Proof that set of complex matrices is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We have the set of complex matrices of the form \begin{pmatrix} z&w\\ -\overline w& \overline z\end{pmatrix}
I know the answer is no, but when I check the fact that multiplication with respect to addition is distributive I get the true equality. From this it follows that the given set of matrices is not an abelian group. To prove that a set is a group, it is necessary to check 3 properties:

a)associativity - correct;

b) the identity element is
\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\ 0& 0\end{pmatrix}

c)the inverse element is
\begin{pmatrix} -z&-w\\ \overline w& -\overline z\end{pmatrix}

d) From here I conclude it is an abelian with respect to addition

where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Why does it follow “that the given set of matrices is not an abelian group”?

Comment: That's the quaternions! In this direction, note the determinant of such a matrix is $|z|^2+|w|^2$, so every nonzero element is invertible with respect to multiplication.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos By definition of ring we need 2 properties to be hold. First that this set is an abelian group. Second that multiplication with respect to addition is distributive. I checked the second property and found its true. That's why I conclude that this set should not be an abelian group. Am I mistaken that multiplication with respect to addition is distributive?

Comment: Maybe you're trying to prove that it's not a COMMUTATIVE ring? It looks like you HAVE verified that it is a ring. Multiplication is not commutative though.

Comment: @Nick no, i'm trying to show that it is not a ring. I know that the answer to this task that this set is not ring, but can't figure out why

Comment: How do you know the answer is "no"? As Mike F commented above, this is the matrix representation of the Quaternions, which is a ring. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations

Comment: @Nick  thanks a lot, I found that there was a mistake in my lector's notes

Comment: I am sorry, but I still have no clue whatsoever about how you deduced “this set should not be an abelian group”.

Comment: It is immediate that $\{ \begin{pmatrix} z&w\\ -\overline w& \overline z\end{pmatrix},(w,z)\in \Bbb{C}^2\}$ is a group for the addition, a short calculation shows that it is closed for the matrix multiplication, it contains the identity matrix, whence it is a unital subring of $M_2(\Bbb{C})$.